# Create XDocument with xml datatype from SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this table:
ID|FILE

1 | ROOT>
     ELEMENT TYPE="DATABASE" CNNSTR="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=testForDLL;Integrated        Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" QUERY="SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE id=1"/>
   ROOT>

2 |ROOT
     ELEMENT TYPE="DATABASE" CNNSTR="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=testForDLL;Integrated        Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" QUERY="SELECT * FROM TBL2 WHERE id=1"/>
   ROOT>

And i want to load the value from the 2nd column and create a XDOCUMENT with that.
So far i have this code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnstr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();

                com.CommandText = "SELECT [FILE] FROM XML_Config WHERE id=" + id;
                XDocument doc2 = new XDocument();

                XmlReader dtRead = com.ExecuteXmlReader();

                if (dtRead.Read())
                    doc2.Load(dtRead); -> This line has an error
            }
```

Ask anything you want in order to help me please.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: right now none. I think i solve the problem, but i wonder if it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved the problem with this code.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnstr))
            {
                string xmlstr;
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();

                com.CommandText = "SELECT [FILE] FROM XML_Config WHERE id=" + id;

                SqlDataReader dtRead = com.ExecuteReader();

                while (dtRead.Read())
                    xmlstr= dtRead.GetSqlString(0).ToString();
                XDocument docBD = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);

                return docBD;
            }
```

Do you think it's the best solution?